# Freeform viewcontroller xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

can anybody tell me how to make a viewcontroller like this in the picture, taller x3 than normal view controller. And how does it show the next view controller if you enable the switch button not a segue!

[image: Second viewcontroller]

[image: First view controller]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Size Inspector` in your storyboard. Set the simulated size to Freeform and change the height as needed:
[image: Size Inspector]

Comment: it worked, i cant give you plus points im not allowed. thanks

Comment: Remember me when you get enough points, then! But I believe you can select an answer as the best answer at any point level? There should be a check button below the +1/-1 arrows

Comment: @AlecO when i am trying to freeform the viewcontroller height more than 4000 ,i am getting black color screen.what's the problem?

Comment: Sounds like an Xcode bug. Typically if you're making a view that tall (like a scroll view's or table view's contents, you should be breaking it out into smaller pieces